# Datatables server side processing

Tags: database, datatables

In datatables instead of fetching all records at a time ,want to display first 20 records and on clicking next i have to show next 20 records using ajax .Will some one of u pls help to solve this problem with examples. I have searched but i dont get the enough data.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "iDisplayLength":20,
   });
```

Also i have used this

```
var oTable;
    $('.paginate_enabled_next').click( function () 
    {
    oTable.fnSetDisplayLength = 2;
    oTable.fnDraw();
    });

oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
```

Apart from this will any one of u explain where i have to change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `ajax` url from where the data will be fetched and displayed.  If you have tried using Ajax please add you server side code,
 would be able to help you getting the pagination done
The below link will help you get it done. https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Yes i tried with this link but for me the entire records in the database of particular table is displayed without pagination.Will u pls say where will be the mistake.

Comment: I got the result but one more doubt pls any of them reply. In server side processing file we have to give the database field name to get desired field records. In my datatable i have S.no, Edit and delete field how can i give in server side processing file. I tried giving space but not working. Pls any of them reply for my doubt.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to map the serverside field names with datatable column name? If so this can be achieved by using aoColumns in datatable

Comment: Yes i am asking that. I have used aocolumns But i am getting an error. In ajax i passed these data as mentioned in below url but i am getting an error  https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html

Comment: If you are using aocolumn then set mDataProp and not data